# Prove that if $a^3 = e$ and $ba=ab^2$ then $b^7 = e$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $G$ is non-abelian group and let $a,b \in G$ such that:

1. $a^3 = e$
2. $ba=ab^2$

Prove that $b^7 = e$.

Hint: $b = baaa$

Although I have hint in this task, I have a big problem.

I tried $b^7 = (baaa)^7 = (baaa)(baaa)^6 = ... = (ab)^3 b(baaa)^6$ but I have no idea what next.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:**  Write the original hint like this:
$$b=(ba)aa$$
and make sure you use property 2.

Comment: I used, and I have $b = (ba)aa = ... = (ab)^3 b$. What next?

Comment: Note that
$$(ab)^3b=(ab)(ab)(ab)b=a(ba)(ba)bb.$$
Keep applying property 2 until you've got all three $a$'s all the way on the left.

Comment: Ok it does work.

Answer (score 3):

*Hint:* Use $ab=b^2a$ to show $b^ka=ab^{2k}$, then transform $b=ba^3$ to $a^3b^{???}$ step by step.

Answer (score 3):

Different hint: if $a^3=e$ and $a^{-1}ba=b^2$ then apply $x\mapsto a^{-1}xa$ to $b$ three times in two ways...

Comment: This is related to [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/337626/please-help-me-group-theory-prove-b33-e/337641#337641).

Comment: I don't see it.

Comment: @user2213654 Applying it once to $b$ yields $b^2$, twice yields $b^4$, and thrice yields $b^8$. On the other hand $a^{-3}ba^3=b$ since $a^3=e$. Thus $b=b^8$.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that I am late here but take a look at this way also. I am using the [Van Kampen diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_Kampen_diagram) to find additional consistent relations. Look at the following graph:

[image]

The path $ABCDEFGA$ is a new achieved relation $$abab^2ab^{-1}=1$$ It will be a good handy calculations for us to find $b^7=1$ regarding to the relation $bab^{-1}b^{-1}a^{-1}$. Just again to @Hagen's neat suggestion (... to show... )

Comment: Nice work, Babak! (+1)